# Is there a faster way to split a text file when a certain token is found?

Tags: c++, text, split

I have a 7GB text file comprised of multi line records that are delimited with a line that only contains the token "$$$$".

I wrote a method to split it by parsing a line at a time, testing for the token, and splitting accordingly. The idea is to write each multi line record to different output files in round robin fashion. My code is below:

```
// Open all temp files for reading
int nThreads = threadData.size();
std::vector<ofstream*> ostrms(nThreads);
for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; ++i)
{
    ostrms[i] = new ofstream(threadData[i].InFileName);
    if (! ostrms[i]->is_open() )
        return(false);
}

// parse mol records into temp files in round-robin fashion
std::vector<std::string> molRecord;
std::string line;
const std::string MOL_END_OF_RECORD = "$$$$";
int curOutfileNo = 0;
while( ! strm.eof() )
{
    std::getline(strm,line);
    if (line.find(MOL_END_OF_RECORD) != std::string::npos)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < molRecord.size(); ++i)
            *(ostrms[curOutfileNo]) << molRecord[i] << "\n";
        (*ostrms[curOutfileNo]) << line << "\n";
        curOutfileNo = (curOutfileNo+1) % nThreads;
        molRecord.clear();
    }
    else
        molRecord.push_back(line);
}

for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; ++i)
    delete ostrms[i];
```

This runs *very* slowly (several minutes). Is there a faster way?

The 7GB text file has 245,634,858 lines and 466537 unique records delimited by"$$$$"

Comment: Why break the lines?  Why not just search for "$$$$"?

Comment: @FoggyDay because I want to write the multi-line records to their own file(s). So I want my 7Gb split into 4 1.75-ish GB files with complete records in them.

Comment: Did you benchmark running e.g. [wc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) on your huge file? Don't be surprised if your program runs e.g. 10 times slower than `wc` ...

Comment: Regretfully wc and grep -c all took at least a minute

Comment: `while( ! strm.eof() )` is broken - use `while (std::getline(strm, line))`.  Given `wc` takes at least a minute, and your program's writing as well as reading which can be expected to more than double that, if outputs to the same drive then the fundamental I/O operations sounds like they'd take pretty close to the "several minutes" you mention already....  If you're desperate to improve performance anyway, perhaps try using memory mapped I/O: you could write out areas delimited by pointers without anything akin to `molRecord`.

Comment: What is that file? Is it some constant data that never changes (with your application being run several times)? What kind of application are you coding?

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely sure that your splitting lines contain *exactly* `$$$$` without any prefix or suffix characters (e.g. spaces), you might replace

```
 if (line.find(MOL_END_OF_RECORD) != std::string::npos)
```

with

```
 if (line == std::string(MOL_END_OF_RECORD))
```

but I don't think it matters that lot.

If spending a day on improving the coding is worth the effort (I believe that it is not), and assuming a Linux system, you could use with care some clever combination of low-level syscalls like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) with a large buffer of at least 64 Kbytes, [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on multi-megabyte ranges, [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html), [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) (in a separate thread), ...

If you access the *same* file (with a constant content) several times, you might consider preprocessing (or pre-digesting) it e.g. to fill some [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) indexed file, or some [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) (or other) "database", and have your real application use these. You could also simply compute some "index" file containing the offset of every `$$$$` delimiter.

As I commented, you should consider that the [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) spent by utilities like [wc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) as reasonable lower bound of execution time. I guess that they could show you that in fact (on your particular system) the program is I/O bound.

BTW, if your machine has more than e.g. 10Gbytes of RAM, you could simply `wc yourhugefile` before running your program. The `wc` process will fill the file system RAM cache with your file's data. See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

We can't help much more unless you explain what is the huge data, how often does it change, and what does your application....

You could also buy more RAM and/or some SSD...